# Inserting a function into directive without isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way.  I am using the `ui-select` directive which does not seem to support the HTML `required` directive.  So I built my own, `ui-select-required`.  It seems I am unable to use isolate scope because `ui-select` already instantiates an isolate scope.

I want to make `ui-select-required` take in a function as an attribute.  If the attribute is present, the it should validate with the return value of this function.  If the attribute is not present then it should validate on presence of a value. This is all a part of a component.

**product_details.js**

```
angular
  .module('ProductComponents')
  .component('productDetails', {
    bindings:{
      product: '=product',
    },
    templateUrl: "/template/admin/products/details",
    controllerAs: 'prodDetails',
    controller: [
      'v3Stitcher',
      'AjaxLoaderSvc',
      'ModelInformationSvc',
      '$filter',
      '$http',
      'current_site',
      function(
        v3Stitcher,
        AjaxLoaderSvc,
        ModelInformationSvc,
        $filter,
        $http,
        current_site
      ){
        var prodDetails = this;

        ...

    prodDetails.templateRequired = function(){
      // Product types requiring a template
      // 3 - customizable_downloadable
      // 6 - static_variable_downloadable
      var productTypes = [3, 6];

      // Specification types requiring a template
      var specificationTypes = ["print_on_demand"];

      if(productTypes.indexOf(prodDetails.product.product_type) > -1){
        return true;
      }
      if(specificationTypes.indexOf(prodDetails.specification.specification_type) > -1){
        console.log('here'); // this gets called
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    };

.directive('uiSelectRequired',function(){
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    require:'ngModel',
    link:function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
      var form = angular.element(document).find('form');
      var input = angular.element(elem.find('input')[0]);
      var requiredFn = scope[attrs['requiredFn']];

      if(requiredFn){
        ctrl.$validators.uiSelectRequired = function(){
          return requiredFn();
        };
      } else {
        ctrl.$validators.uiSelectRequired = function(modelValue){
          return !ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)
        };
      }

      form.on('submit', function(){
        if(ctrl.$invalid){
          elem.find('span').removeClass('ng-valid').addClass('ng-invalid');
        }
      });

      elem.on('change', function(){
        if(ctrl.$invalid){
          elem.find('span').removeClass('ng-invalid').addClass('ng-valid');
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**details.slim**

```
label(ng-class="{'label label-danger': prodDetails.templateRequired()}")
  | Template
ui-select(ng-model="prodDetails.product.template_id" name="template" ng-model-options="{ debounce: { default:500, blur: 0 } }" ui-select-required required-fn="prodDetails.templateRequired")
  ui-select-match(placeholder="Search Templates...")
    | {{$select.selected.name}}
  ui-select-choices(position="down" repeat="template.id as template in prodDetails.templates" refresh="prodDetails.refreshTemplates($select.search)" minimum-input-length="1" refresh-delay="0")
    | {{ template.name }}
    br
    | id: {{template.id}}
    br
    | created: {{template.created_at | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

The problem I'm having is that the variable `requireFn` is undefined.  However, if in the HTML I send in the controller variable `prodDetails` alone then `requireFn` has the correct value of the controller variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that:

- You are doing controllerAs: 'prodDetails' in your isolate scope and
- You are looking to reference the function directly on the scope in your uiSelectRequired directive

I think if you switch this:

```
var requiredFn = scope[attrs['requiredFn']];
```

to:

```
var requiredFn = scope.$eval(attrs.requiredFn);
```

You should get what you are looking for. This is assuming that `templateRequired` property has been added to the productDetails component's controller instance.

To reiterate, your issue was that you were looking for the property directly on the isolate scope itself, where it has been added to the controller reference. By doing a `scope.$eval`, you will essentially be parsing the path `prodDetails.templateRequired` -- which will hopefully resolve to the function reference you were hoping to get in the first place.

**Edit:** So the second part of your question in the comments lead me to believe you never needed a function into a directive with isolate scope. I *think* what you are trying to do is make the template model required conditionally. Angular already gives you this functionality through required and ng-required directives. You state in your question these are not available on ui-select, but they are "helper" directives with ngModel. I believe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zojswfx1/15/) is a mostly working example of what you want to do where I switch to required/ng-required and eliminate the need for your custom directive.

Comment: We're halfway there.  That got me the function name inside `requiredFn`. However, `requiredFn()` does not seem to return anything to the directive.  It does get called when I put a `console.log` within the controller.

Comment: Can you post some code around requiredFn? If it is getting called from the validator function, then my guess is you are not returning a value. My answer addresses the problem you were describing where requiredFn was not available. It sounds like what you are describing now is a different problem all together and hard to diagnose without seeing more code or post a jsfiddle example.

Comment: ok, I added the `templateRequired` which gets mapped to `requireFn`.

Comment: You still need to provide more details. I created a jsfiddle where I hope you can demonstrate what you are expecting to happen that is not.

Comment: ok, here's where I got to http://jsfiddle.net/zojswfx1/14/ but when I select `Spec 1` the Template input field should be required...

Comment: I think you need to hit the angular docs... You are creating a validator function for uiSelectRequired. There are multiple issues in your latest code... 1) You are using ng-message="ui-select-required", it should be "uiSelectRequired" (the name of your validator. 2) The validator function should return true if the model is valid and false if otherwise. You are returning true if the specification_type has "print_on_demand", so your model is passing validation. 3) If another control can affect the validity of your model, you need to call $validate() on your model.